# Can I make a shared reactjs validation component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm working on a reactjs project that uses multiple forms for creating entries on several different but similar database tables.

I am using https://learnetto.com/blog/react-form-validation as a reference point but the validation functions are on the same page/form as the fields themselves.

**Question:** Is there some way I could make it into a component that I can reference on multiple forms that all have shared fields with identical names and validation requirements?

I.E Employees and customers both have names, phone numbers and email addresses so how can I avoid code re-use?

Comment: what npm package do you use for forms? Formik || Redux-Form || Final-Form || ... ?

Comment: I'm not doing anything particularly special for the forms actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of best practices is that you can create input fields with entire validation and checking stuff as an isolated component, and reuse it where ever you want, by that you are isolating an specific use case inside of component and resting it as much as you want, also for validation you can use `@hapi/joi` in front-end(I believe its name is `joi-browser`) or `yup`!

joi usage: https://hapi.dev/module/joi/#example.
yup usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#usage